# Organizing i18n source file for data binding

Tags: internationalization, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 SplitApp application written in English. There is a need to add translation into another language.

I have already made changes to all my detail views using [this](http://www.spyvee.com/SAPHTML5_DemoKit/docs/guide/I18NinAppDev.html) documentation and I have used the first approach (jQuery.sap.resources). All translations are in `WebContent>i18n>i18n.properties` file and in another `.properties` file for another language. And it works.

The problematic part is my main menu that is situated on the master page. To build my main menu I use data binding approach. Here are the elements of the menu and how I bind them: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/gageyurovu/1/edit?js).

I still want to use data binding for the master page.

What is the best way to create/organize file with menu elements and file with translation of those elements?

Comment: Is the JSON for your menu coming from the server? If so, you need to pass the locale/language to the server side code and handle the translations over there.

Comment: @stpc, no, the JSON is not dynamic, it's in one of the project's folders.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your question.

You want to use Databinding for your controls and for your i18n - that's not a problem, just use two models and give one of them a name.

```
var oModel = [The model with the data]
var oModeli18n = [The i18n model]

sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModeli18n, "i18n");
```

Now you can bind your normal data using just the paths, e.g. in an XML-View:

```
<Text text="{title}" />
```

You can bind to the i18n model by just prefixing the path with the model name you set before:

```
<Text text="{i18n>SOME_TEXT}" />
```

You can use this approach with any type of model and choose any name you want to.

If I did not answer your question, please explain your problem in more detail.

**Update:**

I used your code to make a working simple example of the basic binding:
http://jsbin.com/wafecaqezu/1/edit?html,js,output
You just have to add the bundle...

Comment: I don't really understand how the source files with menu and with transtation should look. Can you give a small example for both of them? I mean, how should look my JSON file with the main menu, if it should look different from how it looks now, and how the translation file should look, where to put it and what suffix it should have?

Comment: Why dont you use the JSON. Put it in menu.json and load the data into the JSONModel via the URL of the file. See https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f217c46f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html on how to use resource bundles. For the other model you can choose what kind of data you want to fill it with, but JSON would be the simplest solution.

Comment: I'm looking at your example now. If I understand it right, I should have a `.properties` file named "translations" with translations to another language for the "i18n" model in your example. The main question is: how that file should look like? Can you show example for the first menu item ("Add report")?

Comment: It's this format: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/resourcebundle.html